# Why this function has logarithmic time complexity (calculating the nth root of a number)?

Tags: python, c++, math, matplotlib, time-complexity

Last week, I was taking a specific MOOC about Computer Science, and the prof. used an inefficient way to calculate the square root of a number (he later showed other ways as well).

Here's a function implemented in C++:

```
double sqrt(double num)
{
    double eps = 0.001;
    double step = 0.001;

    double result = 0.0;

    while (num - (result * result) > eps)
    {
        result += step;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I know that the `while` loop will be executed (square root of `num` / `step`) times.

And I've decided to use `matplotlib` to draw a plot of this function growth for a range of numbers from 1 to 199 (inclusive), and here's the result:

[image: result]

Then, I compared it to (log(x) / `step`) plot, and again here's the result:

[image: result]

And so, I have the following questions:

- Why it's logarithmic? and why this apply for any nth root of a number (using the above method) not only square root?
- What with that gap between `sqrt` growth and log(x)?

I'm aware that there's more efficient ways to achieve the same results of square root of a number, but I need someone to shed some light on this one.

Comment: Believe it or not, your `function 'sqrt' growth` is exactly `f(x) = sqrt(x) / step` graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct when you say that the loop is executed `sqrt(num)` times, and that makes its complexity √num. However, contrary to the later assumption, a square root isn't logarithmic: it's simply `num^(1/2)`, which makes it polynomial in the grand scheme of things.

A clear sign and visual help is that it's not a straight line on a logarithmic plot:

[image]

The line on the left is a square root, and the line on the right is a base 10 logarithm.

The gap, obviously, is because it's not logarithmic.

Comment: I literally need some sleep. I mistook it for logarithmic.. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: It's ok, I need some sleep too :)